# Validate a List to towards an enum

Tags: java, enums, java-17

I have an enum that looks like this that I need to validate their values

```java
public enum UserRoles {
    ROLE_ADMIN("ROLE_ADMIN"),
    ROLE_CONFIG_EDITOR("ROLE_CONFIG_EDITOR"),
    ROLE_USER("ROLE_USER");
    
    UserRoles(String roleUser) {
    }
}
```

The values are provided via JSON like this:

```json
{"username": "andy", "roles": "ROLE_USER,WRONG_ROLE"}
```

So I'm doing something like this to try to validate the roles sent to the endpoint:

```java
String[] roleArray = user.roles()
  .replace("[", "")
  .replace("]", "")
  .replace(" ", "")
  .split(",");
List<String> roleList = new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(roleArray));

boolean hasRole = false;
for (UserRoles role : UserRoles.values()) {
  if (roleList.contains(role.name())) {
    hasRole = true;
  }
}
```

Which kind of works as it returns true if one of the provided values are correct. However I need to validate that all of the values are correct so in the example above the `hasRole` variable should be false as the `WRONG_ROLE` isn't part of the enum.

A valid call to the endpoint would be:

```json
{"username": "andy", "roles": "ROLE_USER"}
```

or

```json
{"username": "andy", "roles": "ROLE_USER,ROLE_ADMIN"}
```

Comment: Currently you have any role match, but you need all role match, correct? If I understand correctly all those curls only complicate the question and distract from the actual issue - in this case it's better to remove them in order to improve the question.

Comment: Seems to me your search is backwards. Instead of searching for each element of `UserRoles.values()` in `roleList`, you should search each element of `roleList` is in `UserRoles.Values ()`.

Answer (score 1):

If this endpoint `/rolevalid`is under your control, first I would advise to use valid JSON for the payload, like:

```
{"username": "andy", "roles": ["ROLE_USER","ROLE_ADMIN"]}
```

And then use some standard framework to get this data into your app (Jakarta, SpringBoot, etc). The framework will do all this for you, check if all given roles valid.

Do not bother with String operations, at some point it will fail.

Comment: The endpoint is not under my control unfortunately

Comment: You still should use a real JSON parser instead of manual string manipulations.

Answer (score 0):

If all that you want is validate, then you better should do that:

```
var roles = Arrays.stream(user.roles()
                              .replace("[", "")
                              .replace("]", "")
                              .replace(" ", "")
                              .split(","))
      .map(UserRoles::valueOf)
      .toList();
```

`UserRoles::valueOf` will simply find the enum value by name and throws `IllegalArgumentException` if not found.

Answer (score 0):

To validate for all roles matching you need to invert the search:

```
Set<String> roles= Set.of(roleArray);

boolean hasRole = true;
for (UserRoles role : UserRoles.values()) {
  if (!roles.contains(role.name())) {
    hasRole = false;
    break;
  }
}
```

A small improvement is that you can use `Set` instead of `List` for the search - it won't really make a difference for such small data set, but for search only operations, as in your case, it's the correct data structure.

Comment: `curl -X POST http://localhost:8080/rolevalid -H 'Content-Type: application/json' -d'{"username": "andy", "roles": "ROLE_USER"}'` returns `false` when it should be true and so does `curl -X POST http://localhost:8080/createUser -H 'Content-Type: application/json' -d'{"username": "andy", "roles": "ROLE_USER,ROLE_ADMIN"}'`

Comment: @Tallen67 Well, I forgot to reverse the check - it should be `!roles.contains()`, so the code buggy, should be fixed now.

Answer (score 0):

First, I suggest some changes to your `enum` class:

- I made the name of the class singular, not plural. For example, if you wanted to use `enum` to represent the days of the week, you might use `enum DayOfWeek`, not `DaysOfWeek`. I find it is less confusing that way.
- I completed the code for the constructor.
- I added a `boolean isMatch (String )` method.

```
enum UserRole {
    ROLE_ADMIN("ROLE_ADMIN"),
    ROLE_CONFIG_EDITOR("ROLE_CONFIG_EDITOR"),
    ROLE_USER("ROLE_USER");
    private final String roleName;

    UserRole (String roleName) {
        this.roleName = roleName;
    }
    
    public boolean isMatch (String roleName) { 
        return this.roleName.equalsIgnoreCase(roleName);
    }
}
```

Now, if I understand the problem correctly, for each user, you will have an array of roles of that user, as a `List<String>`. You want to find out if each element in that array is a valid role.

Given a `String []` of roles for a single user, this code will return `true` if each element is a valid role, and return `false` if any element is not valid. This is an "old dog" approach.

```
 public static boolean enumTest (List<String> rolesOfThisUser) { 
  
    final UserRole [] userRoles = UserRole.values();
    boolean allRolesValid = true;
    for (String singleRole: rolesOfThisUser)  { 
        boolean thisRoleValid = false;
       for (UserRole test: userRoles) {
           thisRoleValid = thisRoleValid || test.isMatch(singleRole);
       }
       allRolesValid = allRolesValid && thisRoleValid;
    } 
    return allRolesValid;
}
```

Note that it will return `true` if the argument is an empty array. This is an example of "vacuously true".

Test:

```
System.out.println (enumTest (Arrays.asList 
    (new String [] {"ROLE_user","WRONG_ROLE"})));
System.out.println (enumTest (Arrays.asList 
    (new String [] {"ROLE_admin", "role_CONFIG_EDITOR"})));
System.out.println (enumTest (Arrays.asList
    (new String [] {})));
```

Output:

```
false
true
true
```

Note that there will be exactly one instance of each value of an `enum`. If Pat and Chris are each an administrator, they will have the *same instance* of `ROLE_ADMIN`.